# How to get values form javascript to yii2 activeform dropdown

Tags: jquery, yii2, active-form

Here I am using a dropdown field.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'value')->dropdownList([''=>'selects']) ?>
```

And the script code is

```
$('#setting').blur(function(){
            var values = $('#setting').val();
            values = values.replace(/,/g,'');
            for(var i = 1; i<=values.length; i++){
                    $("#value").append("<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>");
            }
    });
```

I have text fields, named as Setting,values. If the user enter values like 1,2,3 in setting textbox then that values will show in dropdown field.
The value could not append to active form.

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Id in the options field like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'value')->dropdownList([
   ''=>'selects',
   'id' => 'value'
]) ?>
```

Comment: Value is displaying in drop down